# How to develop experiment to justify construction of a prototype system?

Tags: computer-science, experiment-design

I have worked hard for my master thesis project to build a system that uses an already existing algorithm, just in a mobile setting, which hasn't been done before. Because the algorithm is complex, it required a client-server infrastructure. Now, as I said most, of my efforts until now went into building the system of already existing components rather than contributing to knowledge.

Now my question is, how can I use my system and efforts to go more in the direction of a scientific contribution? The problem is if I, for example, simulate data loss over the network, I could have done that without even building the system. So I somehow want to include my real system in the experiment rather than doing a simulation. What would be a good approach that justifies also the construction of my real system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might think of it in terms of the research question(s), which might look something like this:

1. Is it possible/feasible to use algorithm X in a mobile setting? (Presumably the answer is yes, because you've already built it.)
2. What challenges are there in applying algorithm X in a mobile setting? How can those challenges be met?
3. How does the efficiency/accuracy/data loss compare between the "regular" implementation of algorithm X and the implementation in a mobile setting?

---

Edited to add:

4. What are the advantages & disadvantages of using your implementation over a simulation? I'm guessing that your implementation gives more realistic results than a simulation would.

Obviously I don't know your field, or how novel a contribution your implementation is. But in principle, I think that answering the kinds of questions I've listed above could lead to publishable papers, and could justify your having built this system.

Answer (score 2):

> What would be a good approach that justifies also the construction of my real system?

I don't have a crystal ball, so I can't say anything other than: in some fields, in addition to showing that your approach works well in a simulated environment, it is a *really good idea* to also show that your approach works well in practice.

If your peers value such "real world" results, then you don't need to justify it any further than that.

Comment: And in some situations, the real-world results disagree with the simulations, which makes everything *so* much more interesting :)

Comment: @ff524 Yes, indeed!